# Delaying start of the container

Tags: docker, restart

I am looking for a way to get one of my docker containers to re-start with a delay (after a localhost restart).

What I currently have is:
Computer which runs docker desktop.
Docker has two containers: Webserver and MySQL (which serves data to the Webserver).
Both of the containers have `--restart=always` option, which allows them to restart if I restart the computer.

My issue: after a computer restart, Webserver does not seem to work properly, unless I specifically manually restart it.

My guess is that I need to give MySQL some time to boot up before I start the Webserver.

I was thinking to maybe setup a bash script or look into Compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), but since I am quite new to this wanted to double check if I missed something and maybe there is a more of an elegant way to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use compose and specify that your webserver `depends_on` MySQL so that your webserver container starts after the DB is up.

You should ideally make your webserver resilient to unavailability of it's dependencies.